# unable to predict result to an if else condition in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

What will the following code produce as output?

```
temp = '32'
if temp > 85:
   print "Hot"
elif temp > 62:
   print "Comfortable" 
else:
   print "Cold"
```

Comment: Comparing strings with integers will not yield the results you expect. It will output "Hot".

Comment: `temp=32` not `temp='32'` then it should work as expected

Comment: did you run it and see? This also looks like mit6.00x homework

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing strings with integers. Python is a strongly-typed language: it will not automatically convert types for you for a very good reason.

```
>>> 1e320 > '0'
False
```

You should force a type conversion if you know the values will bot be of the same type.

```
>>> 1e320 > int('0')
True
```

However, if you are defining the value there, please define it in a way that makes the comparison valid.

```
temp = 32 # not '32'
if temp > 85:
    print "Hot"
elif temp > 62:
    print "Comfortable" 
else:
    print "Cold"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly predictable. You just have to realize what is being compared. `temp` is a string, and Python will not parse it as an int of it's own accord. Logically the first character is being compared to the integer (otherwise I believe it would always be a comparison between `\0` and the other number, while this also allows for alphabetical sorting). Find out if you're using ASCII or Unicode (ASCII should be the default in Python) and look up the first character in the appropriate table. Now you can predict the output. Look up how strings are compared with other types in Python just to be safe.